# Parsing CSV file with records that contain commas in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I am trying to read to CSV file and write it to the output file using spring batch

My problem is some of the records in the CSV contains commas "," thus ItemReader is assuming the String after the commas as of different column

For example

```
column1    column2
steve       john,bill
```

if this is the input, then I am getting the output like this, in output file

```
column1    column2
steve       john     bill
```

I think quoteCharacter() can be used here, but I am not sure.

This is my ItemReader config

```
FlatFileItemReader<IrcRevisedData> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

File inputDir = new File(ircReferenceData.getInputDir());
if(!inputDir.isDirectory() || inputDir.list().length <= 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("Either input directory is not present or its empty");

if(ircRevisedReferenceData.getFileName() == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
}
Resource inputFile = new FileSystemResource(inputDir + File.separator + ircRevisedReferenceData.getFileName());
reader.setResource(inputFile);


DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(",");
delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(IrcRevisedData.getFields());

BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<IrcRevisedData> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(IrcRevisedData.class);

DefaultLineMapper<IrcRevisedData> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);
reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
reader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);
reader.setLinesToSkip(3);
return reader;
```

}

Does anyone know how to configure this ?

Comment: You are going to run into issues because your line delimiter is ',' The input file lines are either delimited with spaces or maybe a tab. Either way you need to specify the delimiter accordingly

Comment: @johnnyutts I am parsing CSV file, that's why set ',' as the deliminiter. how should I configure deliminiter for this case ?

Comment: The columns in your input file are delimited with spaces or a tab, they aren't delimited with a ','. You can specify the delimiter in your reader, but it will need to match the delimiting characters in your input file

Comment: @johnnyutts the above example is not original file, that just example!, my original file is a CSV file which has comma separated values like a normal csv file.

Comment: @johnnyutts do you know how can I handle this ?